# Why does malloc() return a high address?

Tags: c++, macos

I have a source file:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    void *p = std::malloc(8192);
    std::cout << std::hex << (size_t)p << std::endl;
    std::free(p);
}
```

I compiled it on two platforms: (a) on macOS, with clang++ 4.2.1, and (b) on Linux, with g++ 7.3.0.

On macOS, the printout is `7fa432001000`, and on Linux it is `257ec20`.

The macOS's printout is not expected. I thought `malloc()` should allocate memory in the heap, and if it allocates memory using `mmap()` under the hood then it's fine, too. But `7fa432001000` **seems** an address in the stack location, because the virtual memory's upper limit on a x86_64 is just below `7fffffffffff` (at least it's the case for current Linux - maybe I was wrong).

My question is: why (or how) does the `malloc()` on macOS return such a high address? Is this because of the way Clang's libc++ was implemented?

Comment: It's called [Virtual Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). The virtual addresses you're seeing are mapped to a physical address.

Comment: @Steve Sorry but I think you are not answering my question. The addresses in the programs are all virtual memory address, and heap/stack/.. also refer to virtual memory areas. I was not talking about physical memory.

Comment: Just because something is the case for Linux, it doesn't have to be the case for Mac OS, so that's not a contradiction. Then, what would be the next returned address? I guess it's going to be less, because the limit grows downwards, which again would make perfect sense. BTW: Avoid C-style casts in C++. For above code, just write the pointer to stdout, it will automatically be formatted with base 16.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt no, it's going upward. macOS: `7f8470801000` then `7f8470804000`; Linux: `c10c20` then `c13040`. Stack grows downward, heap grows upward.

Comment: Different `malloc()` implementations use different strategies. It may have been from a thread arena or per-thread cache, or from `sbrk` or `mmap` which happened to return a high address. For the former, the program's BSS segment may have been located at high address. `mmap` also has `MAP_FIXED`, so doing `strace` or similar should give a better insight at what's going on.

Comment: @minmaxavg thanks. That's the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @Leedehai Why would you expect similar addresses with different operating systems at all? How does that matter in the end?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ purely out of curiosity.

Comment: @Leedehai _curiosity kills the cat_ :3

Comment: Note that 0x7f84xxxxxxxx is more than 500GB below the stack which is usually at 0x7fffxxxxxxxx somewhere.  It only seems close because a 47 bit address space is so huge (128TB).

Answer (score 0):

This is due to modern systems mapping virtual addresses to actual physical addresses.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory):

> The computer's operating system, using a combination of hardware and
>   software, maps memory addresses used by a program, called virtual
>   addresses, into physical addresses in computer memory. Main storage,
>   as seen by a process or task, appears as a contiguous address space or
>   collection of contiguous segments. The operating system manages
>   virtual address spaces and the assignment of real memory to virtual
>   memory. Address translation hardware in the CPU, often referred to as
>   a memory management unit or MMU, automatically translates virtual
>   addresses to physical addresses. Software within the operating system
>   may extend these capabilities to provide a virtual address space that
>   can exceed the capacity of real memory and thus reference more memory
>   than is physically present in the computer.

As to why it's different on two different platforms, that's because different computer hardware handles memory in different ways; BIOS and other firmware could have different algorithms or techniques; the different OS or OS versions do things differently (Linux has different options when you build your kernel); the C++ run-time could be implemented differently.

Comment: Sorry but I think you are not answering my question. The addresses in the programs are all virtual memory address, and heap/stack/.. also refer to virtual memory areas. I was not talking about physical memory. Maybe I missed your point?

Comment: My point is ... The address doesn't much matter. You get what the runtime and the OS give you. It's different on different platforms.

Comment: "My question is: why (or how) does the malloc() on macOS return such a high address? Is this because of the way Clang's libc++ was implemented?" The answer is yes, and virtual memory is why.. Why is it different? That's pretty broad.

Comment: yet no physical address would ever appear in a program, on a platform that uses virtual memory. A program does not know about physical address at all.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. From your program's standpoint, there is a HUGE address space. That's the whole point.

Comment: It should be considered an implementation detail. Unless you need to get the physical address (which is possible) you normally don't think of it.

Comment: @steve he is asking about the implementation detail. That's the whole point of the question.